# Cloning table td contents to div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, html-table

I am trying to get the following result:

```
Button onclick
Clone closet Table <td></td> contents
Append to div
```

Here is my code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.addtofavs', function() { 
    var user_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.userId').text();
    $("tr").clone().appendTo("#favorite");
    $("#tfhover tr").clone().appendTo("#div");
});
```

but this clones the whole table and appends to the div.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please show your full code.

Comment: show a simplified version of the html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're running the clone method like this:

```
$("tr").clone().appendTo("#favorite");
```

This will clone the entire matched set - every `<tr>` element in the document.  If you want to clone specific `<td>` elements, you need to target them specifically.  I think that's where you were going in setting the `user_id` variable, but you didn't do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your `HTML` code but here's an example of appending and removing <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/928Xm/)**</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><button class="addtofavs">+</button></td>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>    
    <td>2</td>
    <td><button class="addtofavs">+</button></td>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>    
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td><button class="addtofavs">+</button></td>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>   
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td><button class="addtofavs">+</button></td>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>    
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td><button class="addtofavs">+</button></td>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="favorite"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  height: 22px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  line-height: 22px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
td:first-child {
  width: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 133px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.fav {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 2px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.rem {
  background: #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -17px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 0 3px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $('.addtofavs').on('click', function() { 
    $('#favorite').append('<span class="fav">'+$(this).parent('td').prev().text()+'</span>'); 
  });
  $(document).on('mouseover','.fav', function() {
    $(this).prepend('<span class="rem">Remove</span>');        
  }).on('mouseleave','.fav', function() {
    $('.rem').remove();
  });
  $(document).on('click','.rem', function() {
    $(this,'.rem').parent().remove();
  });
});
```